# C# Замена текста в PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Пользуюсь библиотекой **Itextsharp**. Мой код почему то не хочет работать, он то сохраняет файл, но не открывает или он вообще не создаётся. В чём может быть проблема?
код:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\SHABLONE2_0.pdf"))
{
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
str.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
str.Replace("{A4}", Convert.ToString(this.dataGridView4.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value));
str.Replace("{B5}", Convert.ToString(this.dataGridView4.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value));
}
SaveFileDialog opf2 = new SaveFileDialog();
opf2.Filter = "PDF отчёт|*.pdf";
opf2.ShowDialog();
reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: А что этот код должен делать? Судя по коду `str` нигде не используется. `opf2` тоже отрабатывает впустую.

Comment: str используется в 7-8 строчки кода ( где replace).
opf2 я так и не понял как передать туда значения чего сохранять.
Код открывает шаблон PDF, через for (2 страницы) прогоняет весь текст и меняет одно на другое (другое берётся из таблицы в программе) и это должно сохранятся

Comment: Расскажите что именно должно сохраняться, в каком формате и как Вы уже пытались написать сохранение. Сейчас в примере ничего не сохраняется и он несколько сбивает с толку.

Comment: @defaultlocale В формате PDF должно сохраняться (там сейчас нету кода куда сохраняться, но в " `opf2.Filter` " формат написан). Вот как передать туда данные я что-то не могу понять.. типо `itextsharp.saveas(reader)` не нашёл кода

Comment: Если просто строку сохранить в виде PDF, то можете посмотреть любой пример записи в iTextSharp ([Hello World](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/)). Но я думаю что Вам нужно сохранить форматирование как в оригинальном шаблоне и здесь я не уверен что есть универсальный способ.

Comment: @defaultlocale да я видел эти примеры, они были все через "interop" или обычную конвертацию в DocX, да и это не совсем подходит для моей задачи, ибо как мы знаем, такие конвертации зачастую кривые в итоге

Comment: По ссылке ни interop ни конвертации нет. Простейший пример записи строки текста в PDF файл.